# Stopping motor DC with 2 limit switches

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, motor

I try to build an automatic roof with rain sensor input, when it's rain the roof then closed pulled by DC motor on the tracks and activate a buzzer. When it reach the end (limit switch pressed) then the motor stopped and buzzer off. And when the rain stopped, motor will turning again to open the roof until the second limit switch pressed to stop the DC motor.

I have try to make my own program but it have an error, when it's has no rain detected the motor spin to close the roof and stop when limit switch pressed (LOW logic), but when rain detected the buzzer turned on but the motor doesn't spin at all. Here is my code, I'm using L293D for motor driver and using its enable pin.

```
void setup() {
  digitalWrite(enable_motor, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor_open, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor_close, LOW);
  digitalWrite(alarm, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (analogRead(rainSensor) < 650){
    digitalWrite(alarm, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor_close, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor_open, LOW);
  }
  else if (digitalRead(stop_close) == LOW){
    digitalWrite(alarm, LOW);
    digitalWrite(enable_motor, LOW);
  }
  else if (analogRead(rainSensor) > 850){
    digitalWrite(alarm, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor_close, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor_open, HIGH);
  }
  else if (digitalRead(stop_open) == LOW){
    digitalWrite(alarm, LOW);
    digitalWrite(enable_motor, LOW);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(enable_motor, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(alarm, LOW);
  }
}
```

Can I use If-Else logic? Or I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off. For example, when it is raining and `rainSensor < 650`, only that part of the `if` gets executed and the `else if` parts never happen.

You could just wait for the roof to open/close in a loop. Also, you will find it helpful to break your code into smaller functions. (I'm not sure what the `enable_motor` pin is for, so that part may need fixing).

```
// This function determines the current status of the roof
enum {OPEN, CLOSED, OPENING, CLOSING, UNKNOWN};
byte get_roof_status()
{
    if (digitalRead(stop_close) == LOW) return CLOSED;
    else if (digitalRead(stop_open) == LOW) return OPEN; // Fixed typo
    else if (digitalRead(motor_open) == HIGH) return OPENING;
    else if (digitalRead(motor_close) == HIGH) return CLOSING;
    return UNKNOWN;
}

// Helper functions
void open_roof() {
    digitalWrite(alarm, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(enable_motor, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor_close, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor_open, HIGH);
    // Loop until roof is open
    while (OPEN != get_roof_status()) /* NULL */;
    stop();
}
void close_roof() {
    digitalWrite(alarm, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(enable_motor, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor_open, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor_close, HIGH);
    // Loop until roof is closed
    while (CLOSED != get_roof_status()) /* NULL */;
    stop();
}
void stop() {
    digitalWrite(alarm, LOW);
    digitalWrite(enable_motor, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor_open, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor_close, LOW);
}

void setup() {
  // Set the pinmodes
  pinMode(enable_motor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_open, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_close, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stop_close, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(stop_open, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(alarm, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(enable_motor, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor_open, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor_close, LOW);
  digitalWrite(alarm, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // This function is much simpler now
  if (analogRead(rainSensor) < 650) {
    close_roof();
  }
  else if (analogRead(rainSensor) > 850){
    open_roof();
  }
}
```

Comment: `enable_motor` is for enabling two input in L293D because I use its enable pin. I have try using your code structure, it works for opening the roof, but when motor start to spin for closing the roof and it hit the limit switch it suddenly reversing the motor spin and back to open the roof. Did I missed something?

Comment: There was a typo in `get_roof_status()` and the `enable_motor` logic was reversed. I've fixed these issues. I don't have any spare motors laying around but I do have some L293D chips. I simulated this (with LEDs and push buttons) and it seems to work.